# How to insert text in to a word document from Rich Text Box

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I have a rich text box in my c# application and it contains different lines of text(one to many lines). I want to get those lines and insert it to a Word document with the font and the font size I want. This is how it should look like.

> OBSERVATIONS:
>
> - Line 1 from the rich text box
> - Line 2 from the rich text box
> - Line 3 from the rich text box

I want this to happen by using interop library.

I need some sample code for this since I'm a newbie

Comment: In my experience working with interop library is difficult, it's not well documented and it has bugs. So check other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the OpenXML SDK Package:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

And then do something like the following:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

const string fileName = @"C:\YourFile.docx";
string dataToInsert = txtYourRichTextBox.Text;

using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
{
   var doc = document.MainDocumentPart.Document;
   document.Body.Append(dataToInsert);
   document.Save();
}
```

Comment: I don't enter the bullets in the rich text box. Just the lines. Will this code also generate the bullets?

Comment: and how to add styles to these lines?

Comment: It will not add the bullets. You will have to do some research and experiment yourself to get the format you require

Comment: I don't have time to research Darren. That's the problem. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @aroshlakshan, that's how this works, you come up with what you can do and ask the question, then hopefully someone is kind enough to help you figure out the rest. "Do my work for me" rarely works.