# paste richtextformat in word without using of the clipboard or creating new word file

Tags: c#, ms-word, richtextbox

Is there any way to insert richtextbox text that uses colors in word without using the clipboard or creating a new word file?

```
Word.Selection sel = wordApp.Selection;
sel.InsertAfter(richTextBox2.SelectedRtf);
```

This is inserts raw RTF code

Comment: create a word file from your code (and obviously add text to the file)?

Comment: I have to parse multiple RTF pieces so otherwise I get for every created document like 10 RTF files

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: To use something like this Word.Selection sel = wordApp.Selection;
sel.InsertAfter(richTextBox2.SelectedRtf); in code but something that works without creating new files or using the clipboard

Comment: if you don't want to create a new file, I don't understand where should the text to be copied to

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Isnt there a option without copied text in a perfect word would 
Word.Insert(richTextbox.SelectedRtf, TextFormat.Rtf) be nice

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Sorry it automaticly copied where I was searching for

Comment: Question is basically how can I use InterOp to insert RTF into a newly created Word Application? This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10362152/945456 Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14711659/945456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: save the content of your richtextbox to a temporary .rtf file

Step 2: Collapse your Selection to the end or better yet: use a Range object instead of Selection

Step 3: `Selection.InsertFile([pathtoyourtemprtf], Link:=False)`

Step 4: You can now safely delete your temporary rtf file.

Will that do?

Comment: Actually I was looking for something without clipboard or temporary files. But everyone is saying the same to use clipboard or temporary files so ill just stick with clipboard